# EvARobot: Huge error output while catkin_make

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/3d5357b47644fc77366a33e92f4d6a75

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313518/evarobot:-huge-error-output-while-catkin_make/) by [metobom](https://answers.ros.org/users/39588/metobom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With C/C++ errors, it typically suffices to check the first error. In this case that would be:

> ```
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/random:35:0,
> ```

```
                 from /usr/include/ignition/math2/ignition/math/Rand.hh:20,
                 from /usr/include/ignition/math2/ignition/math.hh:18,
                 from /usr/include/sdformat-4.0/sdf/Param.hh:34,
                 from /usr/include/sdformat-4.0/sdf/Element.hh:24,
                 from /usr/include/sdformat-4.0/sdf/sdf.hh:5,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/common/Plugin.hh:42,
                 from /home/metobom/m3_ws/src/evarobot_simulator/evarobot_gazebo/include/plugins/im_gazebo_ros_sonar.h:32,
                 from /home/metobom/m3_ws/src/evarobot_simulator/evarobot_gazebo/src/im_gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:29:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support \
```

which tells us that `evarobot_simulator/evarobot_gazebo` (or one of its direct dependencies) appears to require a C++11 enabled compiler.

As you tagged this `kinetic`, I assume you are running this on Ubuntu Xenial, which comes with GCC 5.4 by default, which afaik doesn't enable C++11 automatically.

Perhaps `evarobot_simulator/evarobot_gazebo` should enable C++11 in its build scripts (ie: `CMakeLists.txt`), but that would be something to ask the developers / maintainers.

---

Edit: according to [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/evarobot/Tutorials/indigo/PC%20Installation), the instructions are for Ubuntu Indigo:

> These instructions will guide you through installing software and configuring your PC to communicate with the evarobot. You should install Ubuntu 14.04 operating system and ROS Indigo to your PC.

C++11 would not be enabled there by default either, but it could be that the requirement for C++11 comes from one of the *dependencies of the evarobot packages*, in which case changing to a newer platform could have introduced that without the evarobot packages themselves having changed.

---

Edit 2: and according to [inomuh/evarobot_simulator#1](https://github.com/inomuh/evarobot_simulator/issues/1), changes are needed to the various packages before they will build on Kinetic.

I'd ask the developers whether they support Ubuntu Xenial + ROS Kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [metobom](https://answers.ros.org/users/39588/metobom/) on 2019-01-23**:
How can I compile with C++11? Is there any way to do it? And I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-23**:
I would expect the developers of the `evarobot` pkgs to have configured things correctly for you, so I would make sure you are using a supported platform first, before trying to change things.

re: Ubuntu 16.04: that is Ubuntu Xenial.

**Comment by [metobom](https://answers.ros.org/users/39588/metobom/) on 2019-01-23**:
Thanks a lot I managed. I followed https://github.com/inomuh/evarobot_simulator/issues/1.